# Spring data elasticsearch's CriteriaQuery vs SearchQuery

Tags: elasticsearch, spring-data-elasticsearch

I am in reference to Spring Data Elasticsearch's **`CriteriaQuery`** and **`SearchQuery`** (both from `org.springframework.data.elasticsearch.core.query` package).

I am not sure when I should be using a `SearchQuery` (or its implementation) or a `CriteriaQuery`.

It seems the `SearchQuery` relies upon elasticsearch's native `QueryBuilders` whereas the `CriteriaQuery` is specific to Spring Data. Is this right?

Can someone please point out the difference between these two types of Query?